# "Fixed" top & left coordinates using pageX/pageY - is it possible?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the code below that will show a pop-up window on mouseover (on a link):

```
    <li id="menu-item-153" class="myClass">
            <a href="http://mylink.com" data-tooltip=".myDataTooltip">Text</a>
            <div class="myDataTooltip">I have some explaining to do!</div>
    </li>


    <script>
        $(function(){
              $("a").hover(function(e) {
                 $($(this).data("tooltip")).css({
                   left: e.pageX + 1,
                   top: e.pageY + 1
                 }).stop().show(100);
                }, function() {
                $($(this).data("tooltip")).hide();
              });
        });
    </script>
```

My understanding of the pageX and PageY events is that they will get the coordinates of the mouse pointer. In this case, it will add 1 to said coordinates and display my pop-up box there.

I would like to display said pop-up box at a fixed set of coordinates, ie. on top of the link the description box will show. I have tried replacing the e.pageX/Y + 1 formula with fixed coordinates but then the description box doesn't show.

Is what I want to do possible at all? If so, how?

Thanks in advance (after 1.5 hour of Googling and trial & error I haven't got any wiser).

Comment: *"I have tried replacing the e.pageX/Y + 1 formula with fixed coordinates but then the description box doesn't show."* That just sounds like you're giving off-page coordinates.

Comment: Well I tried giving coordinates within the page, that I could see. For ex: top 10px; left: 50px; but nothing happened. I also styled the description box with a hideous, "it hurts my eyes" color so that I don't miss it. But I'll keep trying. Thanks, T.J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing position: "absolute".